# How to read Windows Log evt/evtx files using java

Tags: java, powershell, event-viewer

I was wondering is there any java library to read evt/evtx files.

Already referred links

> [How to read .evtx extension file through java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38497285/how-to-read-evtx-extension-file-through-java-program)
>
> [Reading .evt/.evtx files directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117983/reading-evt-evtx-files-directly?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

I found we can use

```
Get-WinEvent -Path c:\path\to\eventlog.evtx | Export-Csv eventlog.csv
```

But I need run this in Windows 2003, where PowerShell is not available.

Comment: Is there any java library available for the evtx files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell v2 *is* [available for Windows Server 2003](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/danstolts/2011/03/how-to-install-powershell-on-windows-server-2003-and-enable-remote-powershell-managementall-servers-should-have-this-done/). Also, there's [`wevtutil`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732848.aspx) for managing eventlogs from the regular commandline:

```
wevtutil query-events Application /c:3 /rd:true /f:text
```

and [LogParser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd919274.aspx) for extracting information from various data sources, including eventlogs and eventlog files:

```
logparser -i:EVT -o:CSV "SELECT TOP 3 * FROM exported.evtx"
```

Comment: Is logparser open-sourced? If so, where can i find the code

Comment: *"Is logparser open-sourced?"* Not that I know of.

Comment: `wevutil` is deprecated now